# How do I get Java ClassLoader to output each class when loaded for the first time

Tags: java, classloader

How do I get Java ClassLoader to output  each class as loaded for the first time ?

Is there a `java` option that can do this or if I subclass ClassLoader and simply add a *System.out.println()* to it before callaing super() how would I make my application use my Classloader ?

Why do I want to do this ?

When running my application with java 9 it falls over with an error, but the stack trace does not originate in my code so I dont know what is causing it. My idea was to output each class as loaded and then I would have a better idea of where things are going wrong.

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a message for ever class loaded? This would be quite some output, given the glasses loaded by the JRE.

Comment: @Turing85 its only a temporary thing, what Im interested in is what gets loaded just before the error is thrown

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`-Xlog`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5) option with the tags `class` and `load`. Like this:

```
java -Xlog:class+load <other arguments>
```

The output would be something like this:

```
...
[0.083s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.module.ModuleHashes$Builder source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.module.ModuleResolution source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] java.lang.module.ModuleReference source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] java.util.function.Supplier source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinder$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferenceImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] java.util.KeyValueHolder source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.module.ModuleHashes$HashSupplier source: jrt:/java.base
[0.084s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinder$2 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.085s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap$PerfCounters source: jrt:/java.base
[0.085s][info][class,load] java.util.Optional source: jrt:/java.base
[0.085s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.loader.BootLoader source: jrt:/java.base
...
```

Comment: Great, thankyou that worked if I just did -Xlog:class+load

Comment: @PaulTaylor Yes, by default it outputs to stdout, but I usually prefer a separate file so it doesn't get mixed in with the other output of the program ;)

Comment: Does that do the same as java -verbose:class ?

Comment: when i used with filename as you had it complained, guess either needs full path or file needs to already exist

Comment: @GonenI It looks like it's the same to me, but `-verbose:class` doesn't allow you to specify an output location afaik, although the advantage is that it's a standard option.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Oh? just running `java -Xlog:class+load:classloading.txt` by itself works fine for me, even if the file does not exist. I don't know why you're getting an error.

Comment: So, correcting myself from the past: `-verbose:class` also prints when classes are *un*loaded, not just when classes are loaded. For unified logging, the `unload` tag is needed to print class unloading information.